# insert into collection gives the error `There is no such publish handler named: undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Simple package. Does something like as follows.

```
CylonMessages = new Mongo.Collection('_cylon_messages');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  class CylonSocket extends net.Socket {
    constructor(name, host, port) {
      this._name = name;
      this.on('connect', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
        console.log('Connected');  // use this to confirm the action happened
        CylonMessages.insert({
          socket: name,
          message: 'Connected.'
        });
      }));

      this.connect(port, host);
    }
  }
}
```

My `package.js` includes the cylon messages and cylon socket.

```
api.export('CylonMessages', both);
api.export('CylonSocket', 'server');
api.export('Cylon', 'server');
```

I also create a simple publication.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  return CylonMessages.find();
}, { is_auto: true });
```

However, nothing is ever added to the collection. The `console.log` runs, so I know that they are running the callback on connect. I do get the following message.

> There is no such publish handler named: undefined

Why isn't my collection being written to? What is being done that's wrong in meteor terms?

Comment: In your publish you're using "GalilMessages" but in be rest of your code it's "CylonMessages".

Comment: why do you publish `null`? how do you subscribe to that on the client?

Comment: `null` is an autopublish, meaning that it will automatically send that data on the Session